# Jupyter notebook not opening from ANaconda Navigator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I get the following error while trying to launch Jupyter notebook from Anaconda Navigator.

what's wrong?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 235, in _resolve_classes
    klass = self._resolve_string(klass)
  File "C:\Users\sshah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2025, in _resolve_string
    return import_item(string)
  File "C:\Users\sshah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\sshah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 280, in launch_instance
    super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sshah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1051, in launch_instance
    app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sshah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 575, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sshah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1311, in __new__
    inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sshah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1354, in setup_instance
    super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sshah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1330, in setup_instance
    init(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 226, in instance_init
    self._resolve_classes()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 238, in _resolve_classes
    warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it installed?", ImportWarning)
TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'stacklevel'
```

I removed traitlets and installed v 5.9.0, but it didn't work.

Comment: The issue is that your different python installations get in the way of one another here. Any reason why you have both anaconda and a seperate python installation at `C:\Users\sshah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39`? I would personally advice to uninstall the latter completely